# Global variable or calling by reference in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node.js, I have code like this:

```
//file main.js
var otherfile = require('other.js');
var myname = 'aaa';
otherfile.setname();
```

Now, I want to change the `myname` variable without sending this variable as a parameter.

```
//file other.js
module.exports = {
    setname: function(){
        myname = 'bbb';
    }
}
```

Can I do this? Do I have to use calling by reference? Or use a global variable?

Comment: Did [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442530/nodejs-global-variable-or-calling-by-refrence/42443156#42443156) help you? If so then you can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/157646) so that others will see that your question was answered when they search.

Comment: Please explain _why_ you want to do this. As stated, it's not clear why anyone would want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to change this variable even if you passed it as parameter, because you would only pass the `'aaa'` string by value, not the binding the actual variable. And you cannot access this variable from another file because it will be out of scope.

What you can do is to pass a **closure** that has this variable in scope:

```
//file main.js
var otherfile = require('./other.js');
var myname = 'aaa';
function changeValue(value) {
  myname = value;
}
console.log(myname);
otherfile.setname(changeValue);
console.log(myname);

//file other.js
module.exports = {
    setname: function (fn) {
        fn('bbb');
    }
}
```